# jQuery object is different from window.jQuery inside Backbone View

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, scope

I am working on a project that uses jQuery and Backbone. Have run into a bit of a snag here working on Backbone Views.

```
var jq = jQuery;
console.log(jq === $); // Returns true
if(typeof WebView === 'undefined') {
    var WebView = Backbone.View.extend({

        'el': '#WebView',

        'jq': jQuery,

        'initialize': function() {
            _.bindAll(this,'scrollTo');
            this.$featuredWorks = $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',this.scrollTo);
        },

        'scrollTo': function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(jq === $); // Returns false
            $(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('href')).ScrollTo();
        },
    });
}
```

Basically, my problem is illustrated by the 2 `console.log()` calls in the script. The first call, on the global scope, returns true, but the second call inside `WebView.scrollTo()` returns false. This means that the jQuery inside the View is a different object!

How is it possible for there to be 2 jQuery objects in the window? It is causing problems for me because I have loaded a custom `$.fn.ScrollTo` module onto jQuery, but it is not working for the jQuery inside the View.

P.S. I load the code above into the browser using AJAX, along with some HTML markup, which I parse with `$.parseHTML`.

Comment: Please [edit] and update existing question instead posting new questions about the same problem. Asking multiple questions won't help to resolve the problem when your exiting question is already on top of the list in [tag:bakcbone.js]

Comment: Apologies, I couldn't find my old topic on Stack so I thought it was not posted. Thanks for marking the topic for me.